# Android Handler leaking

Tags: java, android, handler

In my android application, I am sending messages to contacts.. and it is showing " This handler class should be static or else might be leak". My application is crashing in Mobile phone but it is working in Emulator, I am giving the code below pls go through it and any error if anybody can help please help..

```
 progresshandler = new Handler()
        {
            public void handleMessage(Message msg)
            {
                //progressDialog.dismiss();
                //Toast.makeText(SendMessagesActivity.this, "Messages Sent",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                new ProgressTask().execute();

            }
        };
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To avoid leaking Handler create Custom class that extends Handler class as below :

```
 // Handler of incoming messages from clients.
     
    private static class IncomingHandler extends Handler {
        private WeakReference<YourActivity> yourActivityWeakReference;

        public IncomingHandler(YourActivity yourActivity) {
            yourActivityWeakReference = new WeakReference<>(yourActivity);
        }

        @Override
        public void handleMessage(Message message) {
            if (yourActivityWeakReference != null) {
                YourActivity yourActivity = yourActivityWeakReference.get();
    
Edited :          new ProgressTask().execute(); 
//                switch (message.what) {
//                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Create object of this class wherever you want to use as below.

```
     private IncomingHandler mPulseHandler;
     mPulseHandler = new IncomingHandler(HomeActivity.this);
     mPulseHandler.sendEmptyMessage(0);
```

Edited :

```
IncomingHandler progresshandler = new IncomingHandler(YourActivity.this);
        if (editMessage.getText().toString().length() > 0) {
            SendMessagesThread thread = new SendMessagesThread(progresshandler);
            thread.start(); 
            // progressDialog.show();
        }
```

Edited :

1. Declare this task in your activity :

   private ProgressTask progressTask;
2. Create instance of it in onCreate()

   progressTask=new ProgressTask();
3. Change line in IncomingHandler :

   yourActivity.progressTask.execute();

Thanks

Comment: if (editMessage.getText().toString().length() > 0)
                        {
                            SendMessagesThread thread = new SendMessagesThread(progresshandler);
                            thread.start();
                          //  progressDialog.show();

                        }

Comment: Actually from here I am calling progress handler

Comment: @Jocheved : Welcome..Take care of your crash also..!!

Comment: @Jocheved : And yeah if this answer helped you then marked as accepted  so others can find it useful..!!

Comment: new ProgressTask().execute();

Comment: Actually I am calling this Asynctasc class from inside handler.. where I need to add that line. of code..

Comment: From inside a static class we cant call that